# componentWillMount showing wrong state values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, firebase

I'm testing out a basic feature with firebase with react and rails 4. I'm following their [basic tutorial](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-07-15-reactfire-0-5-0.html) and I've installed firebase and reactfire via npm.

My issue is with `componentWillMount()`. It shows incorrect state. It's showing other component's state. I can push to my firebase db, via the url but getting back the info is incorrect. Logging into my firebase account, I see the correct information.

**Dashboard.jsx:**

```
var React = require('react');
var Firebase = require('firebase');
var ReactFireMixin = require('reactfire');
var ref = new Firebase(<URL>/bids/); // I repeat this so makes sense to be global :)

var Dashboard = React.createClass({
 mixins: [ReactFireMixin],

 getInitialState: function() {
      return{
        filteredData: this.props.data, // this is from another component withing the same .jsx file. Maybe issue here?
        bids: []
      }
    },

    componentWillMount: function() {
      this.bindAsArray(ref, "bids");
    },

  textOneHandle (e) {
      this.setState({
        text1: e.target.value
      });
    },

  firebaseSubmit: function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      ref.push({
        text1: "a"
      });
    },

  render: function(){

  return(
  <div>
    <form>
      <input value={this.state.text1} onChange={this.textOneHandle}/>
      <button onClick={this.firebaseSubmit}>Push</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  );
  },

});

var Data = React.createClass({
  // has no getInitialState
  ...
});

module.exports = Dashboard; // main component
```

Moving `componentWillMount()` and `mixins: [ReactFireMixin]` to `Data` component, I get back correct values because it has no initial state function but I need it in `Dashboard`. Am I missing a step?

Comment: http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/props-in-getInitialState-as-anti-pattern.html

Comment: You're not using `bids` anywhere. And without seeing something of the data  that you expect to see and what is actually showing up, it's going to be hard to help. Can you set up a minimal reproduction of the problem on a site like jsfiddle/jsbin?